# Restrict form field in CreateView to not show current-user as a choice in template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am using simple forms and the generic CBV UpdateView to all a user to use "tokens" to give other users extra-credit.  A user should not be allowed to give themselves extra-credit, so they should not show-up in the select field as a choice.  I am not using a model form here and would like to know how to do this without doing so. Here is my code thus far:

models.py

```
class ExtraCredit(models.Model):
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(Developer, related_name='extracredit_recipient')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Developer, related_name='extracredit_sender')
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, related_name='extracredit_skill')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_credited = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s -> %s %s - %s' % (self.sender.user.first_name, self.recipient.user.last_name, self.recipient.user.first_name, self.recipient.user.last_name, self.skill.name)
```

views.py

```
class ExtraCreditCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ExtraCredit
    template_name = 'extracredit_create.html'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(ExtraCreditCreateView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['recipient'].queryset = ExtraCredit.objects.exclude(recipient=user)
        self.fields['description'].help_text = "Why does this user deserve extra credit?"

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ExtraCreditCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('my_developer_details')

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save(commit=False)
        sender = get_object_or_404(Developer, user_id=self.request.user.id)
        extra_credit_tokens = Developer.objects.get(user_id=sender.user_id).extra_credit_tokens

        if extra_credit_tokens:
            Developer.objects.filter(user_id=sender.user_id).update(extra_credit_tokens=extra_credit_tokens-1)

            form.instance.sender = sender
            form.save()

            return super(ExtraCreditCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The user does not have enough tokens")

    fields = ['recipient', 'skill', 'description']
```

The only reason I have the `get_form_kwargs(self)` function is to try to use `self.request.user` in the `def __init__` function.  If I use self.request.user in the `__init__` function, I get an error that request is not an attribute of `ExtraCreditCreateView`.  If I do add request to the options, like `__init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):` then I get an error about needing two arguments and only supplying one.  The way it is set up now, I get a TypeError: `list indices must be integers, not str`.

What would be the correct way to make sure that the current logged-in user is not in the 'recipient' field when the form is created in the template?

UPDATED SOLUTION (Based on @Alasdair's Answer):

```
class ExtraCreditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExtraCredit
        exclude = ['id', 'sender', 'date_credited']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(ExtraCreditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['recipient'].queryset = self.fields['recipient'].queryset.exclude(user_id=user.id)
        self.fields['description'].help_text = "Why does this user deserve extra credit?"

class ExtraCreditCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'extracredit_create.html'
    form_class = ExtraCreditForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ExtraCreditCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('my_developer_details')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save(commit=False)
        sender = get_object_or_404(Developer, user_id=self.request.user.id)
        extra_credit_tokens = Developer.objects.get(user_id=sender.user_id).extra_credit_tokens

        if extra_credit_tokens:
            Developer.objects.filter(user_id=sender.user_id).update(extra_credit_tokens=extra_credit_tokens-1)

            form.instance.sender = sender
            form.save()

            return super(ExtraCreditCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The user does not have enough tokens")
```

Comment: You can't do this without defining a ModelForm. Your view is not a form and there is no point overriding its init method or trying to access `self.fields`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that you want to avoid defining a model form, but that's the best approach here. It *might* be possible to hack the form's fields in the [`get_form`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/779829662d48a54ac427574e5e0c279b69519e42/django/views/generic/edit.py#L39) method, but you shouldn't do this.

Setting the recipient's queryset belongs in the form, not the view's `__init__` method.

```
class ExtraCreditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(ExtraCreditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['recipient'].queryset = ExtraCredit.objects.exclude(recipient=user)
        self.fields['description'].help_text = "Why does this user deserve extra credit?"
```

Then remove the `__init__` method from your view, and set `form_class` so that it uses your model form. You have already updated `get_form_kwargs` to pass the user to the form's `__init__` method, so you shouldn't have to make any other changes. Your `form_invalid` method isn't doing anything special, so you can remove it.

```
class ExtraCreditCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = ExtraCreditForm
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks!  you lead me into the right direction.  I am posting my final solution as an update above, but the main change is this: `self.fields['recipient'].queryset = self.fields['recipient'].queryset.exclude(user_id=user.id)` to exclude the current user.